# prettier indent - multiple Ternary Operator

Tags: vue.js, prettier

I am using prettier and use multiple ternary operator in my code. I have checked prettier [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) but it seems not providing for good indent. Is there any way to achieve?

e.g.

```
? x : y ? a : b;
```

becomes

```
? x 
: y
? a
:b;
```

How I can format like below?

```
? x
: y
    ? a 
    : b;
```

Comment: I believe at this moment ternary indentation is an open issue in Prettier (see https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5814 ). As an alternative some people use prettierx (or prettier-plugin-x which merges both) with option `--offset-ternary-expressions true`

Answer (score 2):

As Jhilton says, this is [ongoing issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5814). indentation is an open issue in Prettier (see github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5814 ).

As an alternative some people use prettierx (or prettier-plugin-x which merges both) with option `--offset-ternary-expressions true`